OM SDK integration in android Native
strong textI am trying to integrate OM SDK in android app which have the native ads display but my impressions and viewability factors are still coming zero. I have integrated it according to the docs provided for native integration Doc link
I have couple of questions regarding OM SDK

who provides the verification URL for the OM SDK is it the third party vendor or the verification script url which we get it from the demo app

Here is my code snippet for what i have tried it
I am using the verification script that is provided in the demo app Here
From the script tracking url which have the javascript function when hit it we get javascript function I strore that function and
 ensureOmidActivated()
        val adSessionConfiguration: AdSessionConfiguration = AdSessionConfiguration
            .createAdSessionConfiguration (
                CreativeType.NATIVE_DISPLAY, ImpressionType.VIEWABLE, Owner.NATIVE,Owner.NONE,false
            )

        val verificationScriptResource = VerificationScriptResource.createVerificationScriptResourceWithParameters(
            "integralads.com-omid",URL("https://xxxxxxx/omid-validation-verification-script-v1.js"), "http://omid-android-reference-app/sendMessage?msg="
        )
        val partner = Partner.createPartner( "xxxxx", "1.4.14")
       apiHandler.getJavaScriptUrl(javaScriptUrl) { javaScriptFunc ->
             val adsessionContext = AdSessionContext.createNativeAdSessionContext(
               partner,
                 javaScriptFunc,
                 listOf(verificationScriptResource), null, null
           )
           adsessionCallback(AdSession.createAdSession(adSessionConfiguration, adsessionContext))
        }
    }


    private fun ensureOmidActivated() {
        try {
            Omid.activate(context.applicationContext)
        } catch (ex: Exception) {
            Log.d("ADebug", "OMSDK----- ${ex}")
        }
    }


My questions
what shall be the https://xxxxxxx/omid-validation-verification-script-v1.js
http://omid-android-reference-app/sendMessage?msg= this I have used from demo app but what shall be the actual url for this.
And how shall I test locally whether om sdk integration is correct or not I have reffered this doc
still didn't get this . Any help would be appriciated here thanks
